# Why does It take longer for my UDP client to send data than it does for the server to receive it?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp

It seems like it shouldn't work like that. I start the clock (on the client side) after sending the first packet (size 10 bytes and increasing linearly 10 bytes at time) and turn it off after sending the last packet.

On the server side (the recipient of the packets), I start the clock after receiving the first packet  and stop after receiving the last packet. Why does it take longer to send than to receive?

Code for Client model (UDP sender)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <ctime>

#define TRIALS 6500 // will have 6500 trials to keep under maximum UDP packet length of 65536
#define SERVERPORT 4950 // the port users will be connecting to

#define BUFFER 65001 // the max # of bytes I will be sending

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    clock_t start; // for calculating time
    long double duration = 0; // final result of the time
    unsigned long long int totalbytes = 0; // for calculating total data
    unsigned long long int throughput = 0; // will be final result of the throughput (i.e. totalbytes/duration)

    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in their_addr; // connector's address information
    struct hostent *he;
    int numbytes;

    if ((he=gethostbyname(argv[1])) == NULL) {  // get the host info
        perror("gethostbyname");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    their_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;     // host byte order
    their_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVERPORT); // short, network byte order
    their_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)he->h_addr);
    memset(&(their_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8);  // zero the rest of the struct

    char message[BUFFER] = "abcdefghij"; //will start with 10 bytes

    for (int i = 0; i < TRIALS; i++)
    {
        if ((numbytes = sendto(sockfd, message, strlen(message), 0,
                 (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr))) == -1) {
            perror("sendto");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (i == 0)
        {
            start = clock(); //startin clock after sending first message
        }
        strcat(message, "abcdefghij"); //will add 10 bytes at each try
        //printf("Trial #: %d\n", i);
        //printf("sent %d bytes to %s\n", numbytes, inet_ntoa(their_addr.sin_addr));
        totalbytes += numbytes; //updating total number of bytes sent
    }

    duration = (clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\nThe process took %Lf seconds.\n", duration);
    printf("A total of %llu bytes were sent.\n", totalbytes);
    throughput = (long double)totalbytes/duration;
    printf("The attempted data rate is: %llu bytes per second\n\n", throughput);

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

and the code for the UDP server (receiver)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <ctime>

#define MYPORT 4950 // the port users will be connecting to

#define MAXBUFLEN 65001 // max # of bytes I will be receiving.

int main(void)
{
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr; // my address information
    struct sockaddr_in their_addr; // connector's address information
    socklen_t addr_len;
    int numbytes;
    char buf[MAXBUFLEN];

    clock_t start;
    long double duration = 0; // final result of the time
    unsigned long long int totalbytes = 0; // for calculating total data
    unsigned long long int throughput = 0; // will be final result of the throughput (i.e. totalbytes/duration)


    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;        // host byte order
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(MYPORT);    // short, network byte order
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // automatically fill with my IP
    memset(&(my_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8); // zero the rest of the struct

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&my_addr,
        sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);

    int i = 0; // count number of packets received.
    while(1)
    {
        if ((numbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, MAXBUFLEN , 0,
            (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_len)) == -1) {
            perror("recvfrom");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(i == 0)
        {
            start = clock(); // starting time when receiving the first packet of length = 10 bytes.
        }

        //printf("Trial #: %d\n", i);
        //printf("got packet from %s\n",inet_ntoa(their_addr.sin_addr));
        //printf("packet is %d bytes long\n",numbytes);
        totalbytes += numbytes;
        if(numbytes >= 65000) //if last packet lets break out of while loop
        {
            break;
        }
        //buf[numbytes] = '\0';
        //printf("packet contains \"%s\"\n",buf);
        ++i;
    }

    duration = (clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\nThe process took %Lf seconds.\n", duration);
    printf("A total of %llu bytes were received.\n", totalbytes);
    throughput = (long double)totalbytes/duration;
    printf("The actual data rate is: %llu bytes per second\n\n", throughput);

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

compile and run server

```
user:socket$ g++ udp_server.cc -o udp_server

user:socket$ ./udp_server
```

compile and run server

```
user:socket$ g++ udp_client.cc -o udp_client

user:socket$ ./udp_client 127.0.0.1
```

Sample results:

Client (sender)

```
The process took 0.238971 seconds.

A total of 211282500 bytes were sent.

The attempted data rate is: 884134476 bytes per second
```

Server (receiver)

```
The process took 0.042443 seconds.

A total of 211214670 bytes were received.

The actual data rate is: 4976431213 bytes per second
```

Answer (score 1):

Benchmarks are lies and especially if you use such a short times and also have packet loss.

But my guess is that there are ARP lookups involved to find the MAC address of the server because this is needed to deliver the packet to the servers network card. Only after the ARP response the MAC is known and the first packet can be delivered to the server. All the time the client has already sent data. Some of them are sitting in the send buffer since they cannot be sent as long as the MAC is unknown (if server and client are in the same network). Some might be lost already because the send buffer was full.

This means due to the delay caused by the ARP lookup the server starts much later to receive the first packet than the client has sent it. But after the MAC is known all packets can be delivered without further delay so that the server will receive the last packet shortly after the client has sent it. With later start time and (about) the same end time the difference in time is smaller, which would explain what you see.